# Nest.js throw an error when run main.js in production

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I am using Nest.js to develop a web backend.

When I use npm run build, the cmd shows success.
[Error Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJ0O4.png)

But when I use node dist/main.js, the cmd shows error. But I'm sure this file exist and in develop mode (npm run start), everything's ok.

Here is how I have imported things in my code:
[Code snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kix0H.png)

Here is entities code in typeorm:
`entities: [__dirname + '/../**/*.entity.ts']`

Answer (score 1):

Try to do something like `entities: [__dirname + '/**/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}']`. 
The error is about paths. My guess though.